Reporting Services error in VS 2022 : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module
I'm using VS 2022 with Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022 and Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022 to generate a pdf report. When I execute the command below, using reportviewer (Rv), the error
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module." is hapening.
byte[] bytes = Rv.LocalReport.Render("Pdf", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
Does anyone know how to solve this error?
generate an byte array with the report

The System.ExecutionEngineException exception is thrown when the CLR detects that something has gone horribly wrong. This can happen some considerable time after the problem occurred. This is because the exception is usually a result of corruption of internal data structures - the CLR discovers that something has got into a state that makes no sense. It throws an uncatchable exception because it's not safe to proceed.
You could check following steps:
1.Ensure that you have the latest updates for Visual Studio 2022, Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022, and Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022. Sometimes, these updates include fixes for known issues.
2.check your code for any potential issues, such as null references, incorrect data types, or misuse of APIs. Also, review any third-party dependencies or libraries you're using in your project.
3.Attempt to debug the application to identify the exact location where the exception occurs. Use breakpoints, exception handling, and logging to narrow down the problem.
4.Look for any relevant error messages or stack traces in the Windows Event Viewer or Visual Studio's Output window. This may provide additional information about the cause of the exception.
5.Pretty much anything that uses either unsafe code, or COM interop is potentially suspect.
Try to reproduce the issue in a minimal, isolated environment. Create a new project with a simplified version of your code and see if the problem still occurs. This can help determine if the issue is specific to your project setup or a more general problem.
